# window.open not showing customized URL in address bar

Tags: window.open

We have a custom protocol handling implemented in our application. Below is the URL format. This is done by adding an entry in the windows registry.

nodemanager:?caller=network_view&ipAddress=10.20.2.30

The problem is, when I launch this URL through javascript,

```
var nodemanagerURL = "nodemanager:?caller=network_view&ipAddress=10.20.2.30";
window.open(nodemanagerURL);
```

It opens chrome browser with blank address (about:blank) but runs the required executables (as per entry in registry).

How can I make it show the actual URL in the address bar instead of about:blank ?
Are there any other methods apart from window.open() ? Please help. Thanks

Comment: The first argument should not be within quotation marks if it's an expression.

Comment: @BobKruithof Thanks for your reply. My custom URL is working fine and as expected. But the issue here is that its not being shown in the address bar when the window is launched.

Comment: Then please correct the code you're​ showing because this clearly gives the wrong result.